# Javascript countdown timer, clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, websocket, timer, client-server, clearinterval

I have this countdown timer script:

```
/** WebSocket Setup */
//var ws = new WebSocket("CONFIG.WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_PATH");

// jt localhost testing

var time = .25 * 60; // change first number for minutes to countdown
var constantTime = time;
var refreshIntervalId;
var start = false;
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

function connect() {

    const ws = new WebSocket("ws:localhost:8000");

    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        sendGeneralMessage('history_timer_1', 'new_client');
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        // parse into json, otherwise stop processing
        try {
            // clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            var payload = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log("RECEIVED: " + event.data);

            // continue processing if "event" field exists, stop processing otherwise
            if (payload.hasOwnProperty("event")) {
                console.log("has event field");
                // start clock is value is start, stop clock if value is stop, stop otherwise
                if (payload.event == "start" || payload.event == "stop") {
                    if (time != 0)
                        time = constantTime;

                    start = payload.event == "start";
                    console.log("start: " + start);

                    updateCountdown();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("value is not start or stop");
                    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                    countdown.innerHTML = "00:00";
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("has no event field");
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                countdown.innerHTML = "00:00";

            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("RECEIVED: " + event.data);
        }

    };

    ws.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log("CONNECTION CLOSED");

        setTimeout(function() {
            connect();
        }, 1000);
    };

    ws.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("ERROR");
    };
}

connect();

function sendGeneralMessage(clientID, event) {
    var message = {client_id:clientID, event: event};
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(message))
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}

function updateCountdown() {
    if (!start)
        time = 0;

    // clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);

    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        let seconds = time % 60;
        
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes; //turns single digit minutes to double
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds; //turns dingle digit seconds to double

        countdown.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        time--;
        if (time < 0) { //stop the setInterval to avoid negative time
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

When the "value is not start or stop" or "has no "event" field", I want the timer to stop counting down and show 00:00.

Right now, when the timer is counting down and one of those two events mentioned above happen, the timer show 00:00 for a split second and proceeds to count down from where it left off before the 00:00.

What can I do, so that the clock will stop counting down and show 00:00? clearInterval isn't working, am I using it wrong?

Edit: This is what I have on my server side to test it

```
ws.on("message", (message) => {
        console.log("received %s", message);
        setTimeout(function () {
                var msg = JSON.stringify({event:"start"});
                ws.send(msg);
                console.log("sent %s", msg);
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var msg = JSON.stringify("hello");
            ws.send(msg);
            console.log("sent %s", msg);
        }, 8000);
});
```

When "hello" is sent, that is when it flashes 00:00 and then continues to count down from the start event before that.

Comment: How many times you see `start:  ` messages in your logs?

Comment: The issue you are facing seems to be related to the timing of clearing the interval and updating the countdown display. The setInterval function continues to execute the callback function (updating the countdown) even after you clear the interval using clearInterval. This can lead to a brief flicker of "00:00" before the interval is completely cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let time = 15; // in seconds
    let refreshIntervalId = undefined;
    let countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
    let ws = undefined;

    function connect () {

        ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost");
        ws.onopen = (event) => {
            sendGeneralMessage('history_timer_1', 'new_client');
        };

        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
            try {
                let payload = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log("RECEIVED: " + event.data);

                if (payload.hasOwnProperty("event")) {
                    if (payload.event == "start") {
                        startCountdown();
                    } else if (payload.event == "stop") {
                        stopCountdown();
                    } else {
                        stopCountdown();
                    }
                } else {
                    stopCountdown();
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

        };

        ws.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log("CONNECTION CLOSED");

            setTimeout(function () {
                connect();
            }, 1000);
        };

        ws.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log("ERROR", event);
        };
    }

    connect();

    function sendGeneralMessage (clientID, event) {
        var message = { client_id: clientID, event: event };
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    }

    function stopCountdown () {
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        countdown.textContent = "00:00";
    }

    function startCountdown () {
        time = 15;
        stopCountdown();
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
            let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
            let seconds = time % 60;

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes; //turns single digit minutes to double
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds; //turns dingle digit seconds to double
            countdown.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
            time--;
            if (time < 0) stopCountdown();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately, this didn't work

Comment: Do some debugging add more context.

Comment: Added more context, did debugging but can't find a solution.

Comment: Hmm is this a better solution then? You may need to tweak some settings but it was running on my side no issues.

Comment: No issues, you may very much so be able to optimize and make this work differently to your needs.